# How to convert a string (json with scape chars) to dynamic object?

Tags: c#, json

Good day everyone, I'm trying to convert a string that looks like this:

`"{\"Estado\":true,\"Token\":\"3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72\",\"Nombre\":\"Agente COV\"}"`

If I do a quick inspection when the code is running, it looks like this:

[image]

After applying the following line of code:

```
var Datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(Resultado);
```

It returns the object with two curly braces

```
{{"Estado": true, "Token": "3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72", "Nombre": "Agente COV"}}
```

[image]

How can I avoid those two curly braces after converting the string to dynamic object?

I need to use it like this at the end:

```
var foo = Datos.Token.Value;
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Did you test the output of `var foo = Datos.Token.Value;`? This should already work. No need to change anything.

Comment: On an additional note: I would avoid using dynamic when possible and instead deserialize your json into a known object. If you are not sure how your class structure should look like for a given json string you can use a tool such as [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: Yes, I already test it, this is the message `error CS1061: "object" doesn´t contains a definition to "Token"`

Comment: You are using `Newtonsoft.Json` for deserialization, am I right?

Comment: Yes I'm using Newtonsoft.Json for deserialization, the weird thing here, maybe, is the string with those characters, but the second thing is that it really converts it to an object, but I can´t access to the properties

Comment: I just copied your code and did a test by myself without any issues. Code compiles, runs and `foo` contains the desired output of "3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72".

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the extra curly brackets `{{ }}`. That's just how a `JObject` is getting represented. Can you please post the complete code snippet of deserializing the json and accessing the `Token`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The effects you're seeing (escaped quotes in the string and the braces) are just how the debugger has chosen to display those values.

```
"{\"Estado\":true,\"Token\":\"3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72\",\"Nombre\":\"Agente COV\"}"
```

is actually a string that contains

```
{"Estado":true,"Token":"3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72","Nombre":"Agente COV"}
```

and

```
{{"Estado": true, "Token": "3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72", "Nombre": "Agente COV"}}
```

Is how the debugger has chosen to display the dynamic object with 3 properties with values

- Estado - true
- Token - "3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72"
- Nombre - "Agente COV"

The simplest way I'd tackle this would be to create a class for the JSON

```cs
public class MyObject{
    public bool Estado { get; set; }
    public Guid Token { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use Json.Net to deserialize it.

```cs
var json = "{\"Estado\":true,\"Token\":\"3D16C8D8-058C-4FA7-AEA2-1A764A083B72\",\"Nombre\":\"Agente COV\"}";
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(json);
```

Then access the values like `myObject.Token` etc.

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can first parse your json with

```
dynamic Datos = JObject.Parse(yourjson);
```

and retrieve the value by

```
var foo = Datos.Token
```

Note - JObject is from newtonsoft

Comment: this gives `error CS1061: "object" doesn´t contains a definition to "Token"`